# How can I check in Twig if an advanced theme setting option is unchecked?

Tags: 8, theming

I've a list of advanced theme option(checkbox) to not display, such as search bar.

I did many research about custom advanced theme setting, but all the samples are
`{% if remove_searchbar %}{% endif %}`. This render if the option is checked but I want the opposite.

How do I make a statement for **if an option is unchecked**? I really don't want to do `{% if remove_searchbar %}{% else %}{% endif %}` or make everything checked by default.

Comment: `{% if not remove_searchbar %}`. See https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html

Comment: @leymannx That works!

Comment: @leymannx can you put that in answer?

Comment: Nah, feel free to do that yourself. 

Comment: @CocoSkin, please add the info as answer and mark as resolved. I would add the answer myself but I don't want to steal the karma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer is credited to @leymannx.

```
{% if not remove_searchbar %}
  do something
{% endif %}
```

After some research I found [twig syntax](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/). You also can find the "[if statement](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/if.html)" syntax and samples on Twig Symfony website.